Academics in the USA that were sponsored for H1B visa, can you tell me about your experience? How long did it take, how was the process?
I am currently being sponsored for the H1B and my proposed start date is mid-August. I am not sure about the feasibility of this as most websites say it takes around 3-8 months to obtain the H1B. Can you share your experience being sponsored, please? How was the process, the timeline, the appointment at the embassy, etc. Were you able to move your appointment date closer? (I will be applying from England)

This may depend on your nationality (I don't know, I'm just guessing). Can you edit that in?

Are you a British citizen?

Processing times go up and go down. Five years ago everything seemed simple, then at the beginning of the pandemic everything seemed impossible. It is different again now. I don't think that asking people who've been on H1Bs more than a few months will give you anything useful.

The employer is sponsoring you and is paying for the lawyer? Presumably they have a reasonable expectation of when the visa will be issued. (I went through this in 2006, so it might not be useful).

Thank you anyway, I am hoping that someone who has been through this process in the last year or so sees this and shares their experience with me..
